# i'm having a hard time injecting sql to my project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

my add statement is work quite good, 
but when it turn to edit data it wont work. 
i'm stuck figuring what the right code should i use.
i really need your help guys!

my add statement is work quite good, 
but when it turn to edit data it wont work. 
i'm stuck figuring what the right code should i use.
i really need your help guys!

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
Dim connetionString As String
Dim cnn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim sql As String
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

            connetionString = "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"
    sql = "INSERT INTO Table_Info (ID,Name) VALUES ('" & Me.txtID.Text & "','" & Me.txtName.Text & "')"

    cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

    cnn.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, cnn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    cnn.Close()

End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TestDataSet.Table_Info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table_InfoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.Table_Info)

End Sub
 Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click

    Dim connetionString As String
    connetionString = "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"

    cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    sql = "insert into Table_Info (ID,Name) values('" & txtID.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "')"
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        da.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cnn)
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("err.discription")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try



End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points.

Firstly, the `INSERT` SQL command is for inserting new rows into a database table. If you're going to edit an existing row, you need to use the `UPDATE` command. It will look something like `UPDATE Table_Info SET Name = @name WHERE ID = @id`.

Secondly, you really shouldn't be building SQL command strings like that. You're basically opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks as you're passing unverified user input directly into the database. You should take a look at [parametrized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).